# How do I let the player create a list, and make the game cycle through that list?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a game where the player can put 4 objects in any combination, even 4 of itself. What would be the best method of going about this, and letting the game cycle through the list the player created based on a timer.

Example: The player has 4 weapons: Katana, Axe, Spear, Chakram. The player can set the order to Chakram, Chakram, Katana, Spear. The game will give the player the item based on the order of the list they set. The game will only give the player an item after a set amount of time.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Runner : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Touch _touch;
    private Rigidbody _rb;
    private Animator _anim;
    private UIManager _ui;


    [SerializeField] private HealthBar _healthBar;
    [SerializeField] private Bullet _bullet;



    [SerializeField] private float _moveSpeed = 0.25f;
    [SerializeField] private float _dashSpeed = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private int _health = 20;
    [SerializeField] private int _currentHealth;

    [SerializeField] private bool _hasZwei;
    [SerializeField] private bool _hasAxe;
    [SerializeField] private bool _hasDagger;
    [SerializeField] private bool _hasKatana;


    void Start()
    {
        
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); //Accessing the Rigidbody Component
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); //Accessing the Animator Component
        _ui = GameObject.Find("UI Manager").GetComponent<UIManager>(); //Accessing the UI Manager Component


        _currentHealth = _health;
        _healthBar.SetMaxHealth(_health);

        _anim.SetBool("Running",true);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
       Movement();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Invoke("GainPowerUp", 5f);
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            _touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            
            if (_touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                _rb.MovePosition( new Vector3(
                transform.position.x + _touch.deltaPosition.x * _moveSpeed,
                transform.position.y,
                transform.position.z + _touch.deltaPosition.y * _moveSpeed));
                _rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
            }
        }

        if (Input.touchCount == 2)
        {
            _touch = Input.GetTouch(1);

            switch(_touch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                if (_hasAxe == false && _hasZwei == false && _hasKatana == false && _hasDagger == false)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Has no weapon.");
                }
                if(_hasZwei)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Player has attacked with Zweihander");
                    _hasZwei = false;
                    _anim.SetTrigger("NoWeapon");
                }
                if(_hasAxe)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Player has attacked with Axe");
                    _hasAxe = false;
                    _anim.SetTrigger("NoWeapon");
                }
                if(_hasDagger)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Player has attacked with Dagger");
                    _hasDagger = false;
                    _anim.SetTrigger("NoWeapon");
                }
                if(_hasKatana)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Player has attacked with Katana");
                    _hasKatana = false;
                   _anim.SetTrigger("NoWeapon");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Damage(int damage)
    {
        _currentHealth -= damage;

        _healthBar.SetHealth(_currentHealth);

        if (_currentHealth == 0)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void GainPowerUp(int _powerUp)
    {
        _powerUp = Random.Range(0,4);

        switch(_powerUp)
        {
            case 1:
                //Sword Powerup
                _hasZwei = true;
                _hasAxe = false;
                _hasDagger = false;
                _hasKatana = false;
                _anim.SetTrigger("SwordRun");
                break;

            case 2:
                //Axe Powerup
                _hasAxe = true;
                _hasZwei = false;
                _hasDagger = false;
                _hasKatana = false;
                _anim.SetTrigger("AxeRun");
                break;

            case 3:
                //Katana Powerup 
                _hasKatana = true;
                _hasAxe = false;
                _hasDagger = false;
                _hasZwei = false;
                _anim.SetTrigger("KatanaRun");
                break;

            case 4:
                //Dagger Powerup 
                _hasDagger = true;
                _hasAxe = false;
                _hasKatana = false;
                _hasZwei = false;
                _anim.SetTrigger("DaggerRun");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What methods have you tried/researched so far, and how have they failed?

Comment: I was researching ways of creating countdowns and then the game giving you a random item at first using Random range with each weapon having it's own number, but I didn't like the way it felt in game. I've been trying to use list's to no avail on my own so I thought I'd ask on here.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far? You'll get better answers (and avoid getting your questions closed! D:) if you give us something concrete to work with.

Comment: Added my script to the main post.

Comment: Hey, hey! Thanks, Edi!

Comment: Update is executed multiple times per second and so is your gain powerup

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call your powerUp on a fixed cycle, you should use InvokeRepeating instead of Invoke, which allows you as a third parameter the cycle when it is called.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html

Do not place it in Update but in Start, it just needs to be called once for calling itself for future calls. You can increase a counter inside your PowerUp that resets to 0 once you hit the size of your array that holds the elements you want to cycle through.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use `StartCouroutine` with an `IEnumerator` containing a for or while loop. It avoids stringly-typed code because you can call the method you want directly (and get IDE support like automatically renaming the call if you rename the method), and it gives you more flexibility to control the looping behaviour.